# Setup Jetty GzipHandler programmatically

Tags: http, compression, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm playing with Jetty `GzipHandler` and it seems to work rather strangely: It only compresses already compressed files.

My whole setup is

```
GzipHandler gzipHandler = new GzipHandler();
gzipHandler.setHandler(myHandler);
server.setHandler(gzipHandler);
```

The browser (Chromium) *always* sends a header containing

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
```

so according to the documentation

> GZIP Handler This handler will gzip the content of a response if:
>
> - The filter is mapped to a matching path
> - The response status code is >=200 and <300
> - The content length is unknown or more than the minGzipSize initParameter or the minGzipSize is 0 (default)
> - The content-type is in the comma separated list of mimeTypes set in the mimeTypes initParameter or if no mimeTypes are defined the content-type is not "application/gzip"
> - No content-encoding is specified by the resource

it should work for both. I'm only unsure about the `path` part, but without having specified any, I'd expect it to work for both or neither.

I used `window.location.reload(true)` to force reload. The headers are rather long so, I'm linking them: [css](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/140702/headers-css.txt) and [png](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/140702/headers-png.txt).

I've tried to set some properties, but without any success. Should I ever find 
`jetty-servlets-9.1.3.v20140225-sources.jar`, I'll debug it. The question is: Why does `GzipHandler` decide to compress only compressed files? It's perfectly deterministic: `jpg` and `png` get compressed (no matter how small) and no other files do.

### Update

Via `setMimeTypes` I could exclude the images. I debugged it and I'm still having no clue, why other static resources never get compressed. I double checked that `myHandler` treats them all uniformly (they all get served directly from a precomputed `Map<String, byte[]>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use GzipFilter and achieve this result. Jetty documentation of [GzipFilter](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/gzip-filter.html) provides list of parameters supported with lot of details. To enable it programmatically, [refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904577/how-can-i-add-a-servlet-filter-programmatically).

GzipFilter is basically a server side filter and is very efficient in handling compression needs.

Sample Filter configuration

```
<filter>
 <filter-name>GZipFilter</filter-name>
 <display-name>Jetty's GZip Filter</display-name>
 <description>Filter that zips all the content on-the-fly</description>
 <filter-class>org.mortbay.servlet.GzipFilter</filter-class>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>mimeTypes</param-name>
  <param-value>text/html</param-value>
 </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>GZipFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I guess, you're right, but using the Filter looks like way more work that doing the compression myself (which has the disadvantage that it may be buggy). What I did so far is handling static resources by precomputed compressed data - rather simpler.

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel. Don't write compression logic manually. It has been solved many times. Adding a filter may look complex but it's not. I have updated my answer with filter configuration, if that helps

Comment: Actually, I've reinvented the wheel and it was probably simpler than getting the filter running (as I'm using no filters yet and no XML and whatever). I'm using it currently for prefetched resources only (this is currently enough; I keep them all both compressed and uncompressed in memory).

Comment: GzipFilter is deprecated in jetty >8 and GzipHandler should be used. Now I'm figuring out how ..

Comment: Not only is GzipFilter deprecated, it's been replaced by a no-op stub that has no effect. See: https://eclipse.googlesource.com/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project/+/master/jetty-servlets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/GzipFilter.java

Answer (score 11):

Here is how I configured the GzipHandler in Jetty 9.3.7:

```
GzipHandler gzipHandler = new GzipHandler();
gzipHandler.setIncludedMimeTypes("text/html", "text/plain", "text/xml", 
            "text/css", "application/javascript", "text/javascript");
gzipHandler.setHandler(myHandler);
handlerList.addHandler(gzipHandler);
```

In this case, `myHandler` was an instance of `ResourceHandler`. By default, the Gzip Handler only gzips responses to `GET` requests with a response code in the 200 range.

Comment: And what is handlerList type? Can you post the full code and does this go in my @Configuration class?

Comment: `handlerList` is of type `HandlerList`. Basically my code looks like this: `Server s = ...;` `HandlerList handlerList = new HandlerList();` `handlerList.add(...);` `s.setHandlerList(handlerList);` `handlerList.start();` `s.start();` I don't use `@Configuration` so I can't answer that question.

Comment: Thanks. I use embedded maven jetty in my pom.xml. Is there any possibility the above code can be integrated in my embedded jetty?

Answer (score 5):

For the next person that comes along, here's how to enable request decompression, where `handler` is a class the extends `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler`. The important parts for request decompression are `includeMethods`, which defaults to `GET` only, and the `inflateBuffer`, which needs to be > 0 but defaults to 0. The Code:

```
    //create server using given threadpool
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    GzipHandler gzipHandler = new GzipHandler();
    gzipHandler.setIncludedMethods("PUT", "POST", "GET");
    gzipHandler.setInflateBufferSize(2048);
    gzipHandler.setHandler(handler);
    server.setHandler(gzipHandler);

    server.start();
    server.join();
```