# Add servlets programmatically with tomcat 6

Tags: servlets, tomcat6, servlet-2.5

I have seen lot of examples for Servlet3.0, but I couldn't find a single answer with Servlet2.5. But I'm sure there should be a way to do it.
Can anyone tell me how to add a servlet programmatically with tomcat 6.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add filters to servlet without modifying web.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192834/how-to-add-filters-to-servlet-without-modifying-web-xml)

Comment: It's not possible in servlet 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can write a servlet that takes all requests you might react on (maybe bound to *.do or the like) and that handles those registrations. But there is no support by the servlet standard and I don't think Tomcat 6 supports programmatic configuration out of the box. However, there might be a framework that does, but I'm not aware of.